# Databricks considering files as directory

Tags: pandas, csv, filesystems, azure-databricks

We are facing an issue on the Databrick filesyste that considers files as directory and we are unable to read files with Pandas. The files exist in the Azure Storage Explorer, and are considered as files as seen here :

[image]

We have mounted the storage with [oAuth 2.0.](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2.html#mount-an-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-account-using-a-service-principal-and-oauth-20)

On Databricks,

```
%sh  ls -al '<path_to_files>'
```

returns the following :

```
total 1127
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   4096 Jan 29 09:26 .
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   4096 Jan  9 13:47 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 136705 Jan 28 16:35 AAAA_2019-10-01_2019-12-27.csv
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 183098 Jan 28 16:35 BBBB_2019-10-01_2019-12-27.csv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 313120 Jan 28 16:35 CCCC_2019-10-01_2019-12-27.csv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 212935 Jan 29 09:26 df_cube.csv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 298228 Jan 29 09:26 df_other_cube.csv
```

​The thing is, the two first csv files are not directories at all. We can download them and read them as csv, but we cannot load them into a Pandas dataframe.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(rootname_source_test + r'AAAA_2019-10-01_2019-12-27.csv',header=0,sep="|",engine='python')
>>> IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/dbfs/mnt/<path>/AAA_2019-10-01_2019-12-27.csv'
```

They are generated the same way the 3rd csv is generated, and the 3rd on is loadable in pandas. Sometimes they appear as files, sometimes as directories and we are having trouble recreating and solving this consistently.

Cluster config : Runtime 6.2 ML (includes Apache Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11)

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: strange, might be worth while to mention your runtime version I know there was some breaking changes from 5.5 to 6.0 - can you read the file with Pyspark ?

Comment: Runtime is 6.2 ML (includes Apache Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11)
The file is readable with pySpark yes.

Comment: since you're using Python 3, can you create a path to the file using `Pathlib` `from pathlib import Path` and then give the posix path to the pandas reader, another work around would be to read it with Pyspark then use the `.to_pandas()` method over kill I know